# initWithNibName .... method not firing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

In my navigation based application, initWithNibName method does not called/fire

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}
```

I'm defining rootViewController (calViewController) in appdelegate like this

```
calViewController *objCalViewController = (calViewController *) [navController topViewController];

objCalViewController.context = [self managedObjectContext];


[window addSubview:navController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Is this is the issue? Please give me a help

Comment: How are you creating the view controller? What class is your first code snippet in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your appdelegate.m do like this

```
calViewController *objCalViewController = [[calViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
objCalViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objCalViewController];
[self.window setRootViewController:navController];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 10):

When your `UIViewController` is defined in a nib file or Storyboard (usually as an `IBOutlet`), `initWithNibName:bundle:` is not called, rather `initWithCoder:` is. This is the case when you use Interface Builder to set your `UIViewController` as part of `UITabBarController` or  `UINavigationController`, and almost always when using Storyboards.

Comment: Yes! I am loading UIViewController from a nib file. Currently I'm doing most of the stuff in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear methods, so my app consume lots of memory (gives memory warnings). If I override initWithCoder: method, Can I overcome those high memory consumption? Or there is another better method ???

Comment: That's a little bit misleading, do you mean from a _storyboard_ instead? If you have a standalone xib for a view controller, you load it using initWithNibName.

Comment: @sajaz It won't help with your memory consumption, but when anything is loaded from a nib (or storyboard) it will use `initWithCoder:`. That includes custom `UIView` subclasses as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. There was an issue the way I define my rootViewController. @Mudit Bajpai's answer help me to overcome it. I'll work on my memory problem. Thanks a lot again

Comment: @jrturton A storyboard is essentially a collection of nib files, and it was possible to load view controller from nib files all along (e.g. almost every MainWindow.xib had a view controller in the objects list)

Comment: That is true but the bald statement in your answer is wrong. If you have a standalone xib file for a view controller and you create this in code to push it or add it to the navigation stack, you do it using initWithNibName. initWithCoder doesn't come into it - it applies to the objects contained within the viewcontroller's view in the xib file, but not to the viewcontroller itself.

Comment: @jrturton I think you misunderstood my answer, I've amended it for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets say i have a viewController named `TCViewController` with

```
TCViewController.h, TCViewController.m and TCViewController.xib
```

and in `TCViewController.m`
i am overriding the below method.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
   self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
   if (self) {
       // Custom initialization
   }
   return self;
}
```

In my RootViewController i want to initialize TCViewController like this

RootViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad //not necessarily this one, can be any method
{
 // This initialization calls the initWithNibname method implemented in TCViewController.m
TCViewController *viewController  = [[TCViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TCViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];


}
```

If you initialize a viewController like this, control will pass to the initWithNibName method in your subclass if you have implemented it.